# Installing nodejs-dev fails (depending on libssl1.0-dev) but I have already installed libssl-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs-dev
[...]
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs-dev : Depends: libssl1.0-dev (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then checking the version of my already installed package `libssl-dev`:

```
$ dpkg -L libssl-dev | grep libssl.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
$ grep Version /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
Version: 1.1.1
```

Then checking the version that would be installed from package `libssl1.0-dev`:

```
$ apt-get download libssl1.0-dev
$ ar x libssl1.0-dev_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb
$ tar xf data.tar.xz
$ grep Version usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libssl.pc 
Version: 1.0.2n
```

Why does `apt-get` refuse to install `nodejs-dev` when I already have `libssl` version 1.1.1 and `nodejs-dev` depends on a version less than that, i.e. version >= 1.0.2?

Comment: Related: [libssl1.0-dev conflicts libssl-dev](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nodejs/+bug/1794589)

Answer (score 5):

This workaround did the job for me.

`sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev nodejs-dev`

Then

`sudo apt install libssl-dev`

Comment: Good! But why not just write: `sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev nodejs-dev libssl-dev`?

Comment: cuz it don't work!

Comment: Really? Why could that be? and How comes?
Anyway what about: `sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev nodejs-dev && sudo apt install libssl-dev` ?

Comment: This will not work, due to the conflict of the package dependencies   Package: libssl-dev
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4
Multi-Arch: same
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Source: openssl
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian OpenSSL Team <pkg-openssl-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 6702
Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4)
Recommends: libssl-doc
Conflicts: libssl1.0-dev

Comment: @cgseller...... Worked for me but I was using optware-ng on an arm7 based nas with an alias for ipkg to apt.

Comment: I submitted a bug with Canonical , it is here:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nodejs/+bug/1861712